# How can the authentication mechanism be changed for api-server in Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a local minikube installation. I want to change the authentication mechanism for the api-server and restart and test it out. All the documentation I have read lacks this information.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have a command line utility kubectl which helps interact with the api-server. 

How do we access the api-server directly???

Comment: You can ssh into minikube using `minikube ssh` and restart kube-apiserver service using systemctl like `systemctl restart kube-apiserver`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666507/how-to-restart-the-kube-apiserver)

Comment: @vadasambar That would be a good answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand, thank you :) Actually, this method did not work for me because I couldn't find kube-apiserver service in my minikube. Hence, I can't verify if it actually works myself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.  The kubernetes API Server, Controller manager, and scheduler are all run as static manifests in minikube.

So, in fact, in your example: Any change to the manifest will *automatically* lead to them being restarted instantly.

In order to make the modification, just use `vi` inside of /etc/kubernetes/manifests on whatever file you want to edit, and you'll see that the apiserver instantly restarts.

To look at the logs of the restart, you can look in /var/log/containers/ where each of the individual minikube services run.