# minikube and how to debug api server error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I dont get what is going on with minikube.  Below are the steps I undertook to fix the problem with a stopped apiserver.
1) I dont know why the api server stopped. How do I debug? this folder is empty:

```
 --> EMPTY ~/.minikube/logs/
```

2) After stop I start again and minikube says all is well.  I do a status check and I get apiserver: Error.  So...no logs..how do I debug?

3) And finally what would cause and apiserver error?

Thanks

```
~$ minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Stopped
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100~$ 

~$ minikube stop
Stopping local Kubernetes cluster...
Machine stopped.
~$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.12.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Stopping extra container runtimes...
Machine exists, restarting cluster components...
Verifying kubelet health ...
Verifying apiserver health .....Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file.


Everything looks great. Please enjoy minikube!


~$ minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Error
```

Comment: Can you please share the logs? `minikube logs`

Comment: you can also start the minikube with `minikube start -v=7` and post the results or check if there is something that could help recognize the issue.

Comment: please run "minikube start" command with the extra parameters to log --alsologtostderr -v=3 for additional logging. See if that gives any additional information. And also see if the below reference help you to restart the minikube apiserver manually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016081/can-we-restart-the-api-server-manually-on-a-local-minikube-installation

Comment: @Tampa Have you tried any of the above suggestions?